# Divide data frame by deciles and compute mean and median for each decile in each year R

Tags: r

Given the following structure of data, I would like to divide the "Category"s in deciles for each year given by "value" and calculate for every year and every decile the mean and median for the variable "value".

```
df <- data.frame(Category = rep(LETTERS[1:15], each = 6),
                 Year = rep(2010:2015, 15),
                 value = runif(90, 50, 100))
```

I have tried this but then I have problem calculating the mean and mediam in each year for each decile (not sure this is 100% correct though).

```
a <- df %>%
  mutate(quantile = ntile(value, 10))
```

I would like to get a dataframe by year and deciles with the mean and mediam of each decile in each year

For dividing the df in deciles I have tried this which apparently gives me a result (not sure if 100% correct)

```
a <- df %>%
  mutate(quantile = ntile(value, 10))
```

For the calculation of the mean I have tried two methods and both fail:

using data.frame

```
w <- setDT(a)[, Mean := mean(value), by = .(Year, quantile)][]
```

and using dplry

```
z <- a %>% group_by(Year,quantile) %>% summarise (x = mean(value))
```

What I am looking for as a result is a data frame with one row per year and decile and their mean and mediam values.

That's how I need the output (with corresponding values in columns Mean and Median and deciles all the way to 10):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Category = rep(LETTERS[1:15], each = 6),
                 Year = rep(2010:2015, 15),
                 value = runif(90, 50, 100))

df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(decile = ntile(value, 10)) %>% 
  group_by(Year, decile) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value), 
            median = median(value)) %>% 
  arrange(decile, Year)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Year'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 60 × 4
#> # Groups:   Year [6]
#>     Year decile  mean median
#>    <int>  <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1  2010      1  55.2   55.2
#>  2  2011      1  52.7   52.7
#>  3  2012      1  56.3   56.3
#>  4  2013      1  53.7   53.7
#>  5  2014      1  53.6   53.6
#>  6  2015      1  55.1   55.1
#>  7  2010      2  63.2   63.2
#>  8  2011      2  67.8   67.8
#>  9  2012      2  67.8   67.8
#> 10  2013      2  56.5   56.5
#> # … with 50 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: somehow I only get as an output one observation for mean and median

Comment: You don't, by chance, have `plyr` loaded in front of `dplyr` do you?

Comment: perhaps... how can I know? and how can I undo it?

Comment: Maybe if you open up a new instance of R and paste my code in, what happens then?

Comment: Bingo. Many, many thanks. I do not know how I had plyr loaded. I went through my script looking for it but didn't find anything. Also I realise now that many other problems were related to that. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it wasn't `plyr` - it could have been something else.  When in doubt, a restart might solve the problem.